# Installation of TeX Live 2015 hangs at "package-specific postactions"

Tags: texlive, installing

I am new to LateX, I downloaded TeX Live 2015 ISO over the internet and mounted with PowerISO on a windows vista (DELL studio, x64bits), installation began but has not finished even upto the time I am writing this. I used `install-tl-windows.bat`. The `install-tl` windows shows this:

```
writing fmtutil.cnf to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
writing updmap.cfg to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
writing language.dat to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
writing language.def to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
writing language.dat.lua to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var C:/texlive/2015/texmf-config C:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist ...
running updmap-sys --nohash ...done
re-running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var C:/texlive/2015/texmf-config ...
setting up ConTeXt cache: running mtxrun --generate ...done
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --all ...done
running path adjustment actions
finished with path adjustment actions
running package-specific postactions
```

@Johannes_B, @Sigur thank you, it has been in that state for more than 120 minutes, so I cancelled and installed through install-it-advanced.bat; the install-it windows also stopped at package-specific postactions. See what I have:

```
writing language.dat.lua to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var C:/texlive/2015/texmf-config C:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist ...
running updmap-sys --nohash ...done
re-running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var C:/texlive/2015/texmf-config ...
setting up ConTeXt cache: running mtxrun --generate ...done
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --all ...done
running path adjustment actions
finished with path adjustment actions
running package-specific postactions
```

@ArashEsbati, I used small theme as you advised but I am still not having headway. See where it stopped:

```
writing language.dat to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
writing language.def to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
writing language.dat.lua to C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua
running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var C:/texlive/2015/texmf-config C:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist ...
running updmap-sys --nohash ...done
re-running mktexlsr C:/texlive/2015/texmf-var C:/texlive/2015/texmf-config ...
pre-generating all format files, be patient...
running fmtutil-sys --no-error-if-no-engine=luajittex --all ...done
running path adjustment actions
finished with path adjustment actions
running package-specific postactions
```

Great researchers, professionals, members of TEX group and friends what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How long is it in the state of `running package-specific postactions`? Unfortunately i don't have a windows to test, so we have to wait for a windows user.

Comment: Also, did you choose to install more packages? I guess that it is downloading something on the fly.

Comment: @GideonEbelebe - Are you installing TL full-scheme?  If yes, run `install-tl-advanced.bat` and choose a smaller scheme.  Install the rest afterwards (if it works out for you, of course).

Comment: Note that you can format code in your question by highlighting it and clicking the `{}` button on the editor bar or hitting ctrl+k. Also, you might want to open your question up to those of us who are non-great professionals or researchers, or even not professionals or researchers at all.

Answer (score 2):

@Johannes_B, @Sigur, @ArashEsbati, @cfr, thank you all; I installed windows update yesterday I think it is the one called `Security update for windows vista x64-based systems KB3059317` ( I am not sure the second update `window malicious object removal tool x86 KB890830` is for anything like that ) and now I am like anyone of you with TeXLive on his laptop. 
Greetings from Nigeria. I did not see a TeX User Group in Nigeria.

Comment: Seems there is only one Local TeX user group in africa, and it is located in South Africa. Feel free to meet with other users and astablish your own user group ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B is there a way I can connect with you or other user on this platform so that I can send message(s) to such a person?

Comment: No idea what you mean. You can ask on TeX related mailing lists or even Facebook for fellow african users.

Comment: @Johannes_B, for instance in researchgate.net, LinkedIn.com or other social media you can connect with a mentor who will teach you one or few things when you have some challenges by sending message and or question to their box directly. Do we have such here (stach exchange / TeX)?

Comment: Please have a look at [SE contacts list / favourite members / "follow" members](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4225) and [How to contact another member of Stack Exchange?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2805)

Comment: and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6164/is-there-a-way-to-message-a-user-on-this-site

Comment: @Johannes_B, I cannot see the user feed icon / button in any of the accounts I have checked.

Comment: Maybe that function was dropped. I have no idea. As the posts say in general, direct messaging isn't supported.

Comment: @Johannes_B, and friends, I have successfully installed now, which of them do I start to use? Is it PS_View or Text work editor, dviout that will substitute MSword, I am not seeing myself getting anything yet, the whole thing seems a bit complex even with books I have before me. Please kindly explain to me as if you are explaining to a 5 year old boy, how I can get started and running in short time. Somebody already assured me I don't need to be a programmer before I can benefit from this great LaTeX. Thank you.

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) tries to explain everything for beginners. It is very good and you should get good results soon.

Comment: @Johannes_B and friends, the book recommended is great, I am following the instructions, but the DVI is through internet explorer and if you pass another command to LaTeX it reflects the previous output. Notepad was not useful, TeXworks editor gives a lot of promises ( the few results / errors I got were 2ru this editor ). WebEdt would have been all the answer only that after a month I may not have access to it anymore. What more thing do I need to read or know so that after grace period I will still be happy belonging to this great community?

Comment: @GideonEbelebe Your comment is very hard to understand.  As a beginner avoid DVI (very few people use that, although it was the original output format of tex)  (I do not understand your comment about internet explorer which is completely unrelated to tex) use `pdflatex` command on your latex files and you will get PDF output which you can view in acrobat or any other pdf viewer. latex files are just plain text so you can use any text editor that you like. Almost all tex related software is free so you should not be worrying about "grace periods" certainly _start_ with the free software.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm guessing the reference to 'grace periods' is about WinEdt, which is shareware and does require a payment for continued use.

Comment: @JosephWright yes but then for an absolute beginner I'd advise start with something freely available or notepad or anything, I'd only pay once I knew that I definitely wanted to use tex.

Comment: Earlier today, I install techexplorer hypermedia browser extension, after which I tried the little 'classwork' by the book: \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
This is a sample document.
\end {document}

Comment: \end {document}  by writing it on the notepad and then writing the directory ( file path ) on the command prompt in-order to pass the code to LaTeX. Sincerely it has been error all through such as no program associated / wrong volume label syntax / wrong filename / wrong directory name etc. ( displayed on the command prompt ), then I tried TeXworks editor, this gave me the result but through I E

Comment: (coment ctd) by writing it on the notepad and then writing the directory (file path) on the command prompt in-order to pass the code to LaTeX. Sincerely it has been error all through such as: no program associated / wrong volume label syntax / wrong filename / wrong directory name etc. ( displayed on the command prompt ), then I tried TeXworks editor, this gave me the result but through I E, tried other examples but not getting +ve results; then WinEdt which first gave preliminary encouraging results but now a lot of questions has started arising in my heart concerning time & LaTeX usefulness

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and friends kindly have a look at my response and help in keeping the dream alive if really you believe it's the best for a PhD student in Mechanical Engineering / a young man who wants timely research results.

Comment: @GideonEbelebe sorry I do not understand your messages at all, I hope you find latex useful, but it's just not possible to answer such general questions  but where did you find techexplorer that is positively ancient technology why did you install that now???? I honestly can not guess what you mean by "result through IE" internet explorer should not be involved at all (unless you mean you are using techexplorer, but that is not tex)

Comment: Sir, I have un-installed it completely now, I read about it this morning, what next should I do? I want to use TeX (LaTeX) not techexplorer only taught it enhanced TeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and friends, I pass a source code to LaTeX through command prompt but this is the response I have: This application failed to start because kpathsea621.dil was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem. After sometime, windows will respond latex.exe has stopped working. I went to check the files under programs but found it there. Now what is the problem?

Comment: that is a low level installation failure (that I have never seen) did you follow the instructions https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html (you could start with the installer `install-tl-windows.exe ` rather than the iso dvd image)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and friends, I discover that for TeX to work appropriately, there are so many accessories such as AUXTeX to be installed with TeXLive, pls kindly tell me what and what they are in order and the procedures (step-by-step) for installing them.

Comment: I have no idea what auxtex is and if you install texlive from the web site you don't need any other software you can type the latex document in any editor that you want (notepad for example) and all other software that you need is included.

Comment: Sorry AUCTeX not AUXTeX. What then am I doing wrong? Why is LaTeX not working yet?